# drop downlist with multiple selection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application. I need a drop downlist where user can select multiple items from dropdown. Also, the number of selections allowed should be controlled by code.

Please suggest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you use this tutorial for dropdownlist: [dropdownlist tutorial](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), it works fine :)

Comment: Can it be used with asp.net and get dynamic data ?

Answer (score 1):

For that you want you could use a `ListBox`. You can't use a `DropDownList`, because a `DropDownList` is used for the selection of a unique option. In other words, you can't select more than one of the provided options. As it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `DropDownList` class

> Represents a control that allows the user to select a single item from a drop-down list.

On the other hand for a `ListBox` class we have that

> Represents a list box control that allows single or **multiple** item selection.

For more information about `ListBox`, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using jQuery:

jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BeerSelection').change(function () {

            var $BeersSelected = $('#BeerSelection').val().length;

            if ($BeersSelected > 3) {
                alert("Hey Bro, you've selected too many beers");
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

aspx code

```
    <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="BeerSelection" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <asp:ListItem>Yuengling</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Budwiser</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Blue Moon</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Coors Light</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Chimay</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit />
```